# how to hide a discount value when it is zero?

Tags: php

How can I hide `{$r["gia_ao"]}` if it equals to 0 in this below p tag:

```
</p><p class="per-discount";>- {$r["gia_ao"]}%</p>
```

Thank you!

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
if ({$r["gia_ao"]} !== 0) : ?>
<p class="per-discount">
- <?php echo {$r["gia_ao"]}; ?>%
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I use this in bootstrap to create a simple ecommerce website. SQL data from another main website.

Comment: What's the curly braces? This is invalid php.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want the curly braces `{}` ?

You can simply type as below

```
/* FIRST OPTION */
if( (int) $r["gia_ao"] !== 0) {
   /* ... do your stuff here ... */
}

/* SECOND OPTION */
( (int)$r["gia_ao"] === 0 ? /* if yes, then do your stuff */ : /* if no, then do your other stuff */ )
```

I am type casting the array element `$r["gia_ao"]` because there are occassions you may receive some numbers as a string like `'0'` or `'1'`.

Type casting will make sure the string is converted into the type you have mentioned in the brackets like I did above `(int)`.

By this you can even verify the type of the value with `===` or `!==` .